# multiple data in array codeIgniter?

Tags: arrays, codeigniter, multiple-columns

I have an array but in array there is 3 to 4 columns that are educational and inserted multiple times inside the array. how to insert that value?

here is my code...

**Controller:**

```
public function insert_admission()
{

    $data = $this->input->post();

    $this->Main_Model->insert_admission($data);
    redirect(base_url('Main/register_student'));
}
```

**Model:**

```
  public function insert_admission($data)
    {

        $target_dir = "assets/images/users/";
        $target_file = $target_dir.time().basename($_FILES["adm_image"]["name"]);
        $imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
        $imgName = time().basename($_FILES["adm_image"]["name"]);

        move_uploaded_file($_FILES["adm_image"]["tmp_name"], $target_file);

        $data = array(

                'session'       => $data['session'], 

                'std_image'     => $imgName,

                'std_name'          => $data['std_name'],
                'std_status'        => $data['status'],
                'std_fname'         => $data['fname'],
                'std_birth'         => $data['birth'],
                'std_cnic'          => $data['cnic'],
                'std_nationality'   => $data['nationality'],
                'std_religion'      => $data['religion'],
                'std_address'       => $data['address'],
                'std_phone'         => $data['phone'],
                'std_cell'          => $data['cell'],  
                'std_email'         => $data['std_email'],

                'off_info_org_name'              => $data['org_name'],
                'off_info_designation'  => $data['info_designation'],
                'off_info_department'            => $data['info_department'],
                'off_info_address'               => $data['info_address'],
                'off_info_phone'                 => $data['info_phone'],
                'off_info_fax'                   => $data['info_fax'],
                'off_info_cell'                  => $data['info_cell'],
                'off_info_email'                 => $data['info_email'],
                'off_info_web'                   => $data['info_web'],
                'off_info_status'                => $data['info_status'],


                //  i want these 4 entities to store multiple times 

                'acd_qualification'  => $data['acd_qualification'],
                'acd_board'          => $data['acd_board'],
                'acd_year'           => $data['acd_year'],
                'acd_grade'          => $data['acd_grade'],

                //  these only above 4

                'off_total'             => $data['off_total'],
                'off_adm_fee'           => $data['off_adm_fee'],    
                'off_exemption_fee'     => $data['off_exemption_fee'],
                'off_id_fee'            => $data['off_id_fee'],
                'off_annual_sub'        => $data['off_annual_sub'],
                'off_courier_charges'   => $data['off_courier_charges'],
                'off_exam_fee'          => $data['off_exam_fee']
    /*          'off_signature'         => $data['off_signature'],
                'off_verify_status'     => $data['off_verify_status'],
                'off_remarks'           => $data['off_remarks'],
                'off_rec_no'            => $data['off_rec_no'],
                'off_date'              => $data['off_date'],
                'off_verify_signature'  => $data['off_verify_signature'],
                'off_adm_allow'         => $data['off_adm_allow'],
                'off_app_remarks'       => $data['off_app_remarks'],
                'off_app_signature'     => $data['off_app_signature']
                */

            );

        $query = $this->db->insert('reg_student',$data);
        return $query;
    }
```

**View:**

```
<tr>
                    <td><input type="text" name="acd_qualification[]" placeholder="B.E / B.S / MBA..." autofocus="autofocus"></td>
                        <td><input type="text"  name="acd_board[]"  placeholder="Enter Board"></td>
                        <td><input type="text"  name="acd_year[]"  placeholder="####"></td>        
                        <td><input type="text" name="acd_grade[]"  placeholder="----"></td>
                    </tr>
```

so these entities that I have mentioned in the model section under comment section. I have to store them not only single time, these are attached with whole form. i can store it if there are only ones, but storing inside the array  output after insertion shows the array. it is just because i have use the name with brackets to store multiple data.
so this is the query?

Comment: use for or foreach loop.

Comment: at where if i use target a value and starts counter and run than other entities are also repeats with them in foreach loop.

Comment: just before formulating data array